# .htaccess Redirect subfolder to new domain without the subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect a site in a sub-folder to another domain, so, inside the sub-folder I put the following .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.newdomain.com/
```

With this, when I access the sub-folder url http://www.olddomain.com/site1 I get redirected to http://www.newdomain.com/site1, but the correct should be http://www.newdomain.com, without the subfolder url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect` directive automatically appends original path to target. Use `RedirectMatch` instead in your subfolder:

```
RedirectMatch 301 / http://www.newdomain.com/
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.